# How to generate "www" in the url automatically when I enter without it

Tags: html, url, web

I have this site [mamgrow.lt](http://mamgrow.lt). I want to enter `mamgrow.lt` in the browser and that `www` would appear automatically in the link after I enter it. Is it possible?

mamgrow.lt   ---->  ENTER  ---->   www.mamgrow.lt

Or should I simply redirect user to www.mamgrow.lt when he enters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create .htaccess and paste this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

See [How to create .htaccess file](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache as a webserver you can do this using a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Here is also a generator for creating proper redirects.](http://www.htaccesseditor.com/en.shtml#a_redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible [using .htaccess](http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```